# Git Checkout Remote Branch

Tags: git

I just create a branch call `release-1.0`
I run `git branch` I got

release-1.0
* master

I checked source tree, I saw that both branches are exist in the remote as well.

---

How come's when my QA run `git branch` they don't see what I see ? 
They only see master. They also did a `git fetch`, and a `git pull`.

What command should they run to checkout the branch that I just create ?

Comment: did you push your new created branch?

Comment: theres a few questions here, @bruce answers how to see all branches below. to check out the branch you simply run `git checkout release-1.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch` shows local branch

To include remote branches, you can used `git branch -a` or `git branch -r`to show only remotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to push your branch with `git push` and then they need to run the commands: `git pull` and `git checkout release-1.0`

Git let's you name branches however you want to. It does not force you to follow any specific methodology. It sounds like you've created a branch when a tag may have been more appropriate. Try doing your development in a branch named `development` and when you do a release you can create a tag to save that point in history. There are many methodologies you can follow, [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a popular one.